# Mad Magazine comic strip about the philosopher Aristotle being a "damn foreigner"

Tags: identification-request, comics, dave-berg, mad-magazine

After the unexpected success I had with my [previous identification question regarding a Mad cartoon by Dave Berg](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18558/289), I feel emboldened to ask another. I remember very few details, but it's something like this: Two men are having a conversation. One man is complaining to the other that the neighborhood is being taken over by hippies and damn foreigners. The other man tries to reason with the first, quoting "Aristotle, the great Greek philosopher" as an authority. The first man shoots back: "Greek? Another damn foreigner!"

All I'm really sure of is the punchline: that Aristotle is a damn foreigner. I may have gotten the details of the setup wrong. For example, the man might have been complaining about something other than the shift in neighborhood demographics. The art was simple black and white drawings as in the previous cartoon.

The strip, like the one I asked about earlier, was from a [Dave Berg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dave_Berg_(cartoonist)) Lighter Side [collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lighter_Side_of...) that probably appeared in the late 60s or 1970s. I read it in the early 80s. I had assumed that those strips originally ran in Mad magazine, but even though they had the magazine's logo prominently on the front cover, the paperbacks were actually original collections, as the [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/18702/289) to my earlier question noted.

Comment: Does the cartoon mentioned in [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/g/alt.usage.english/c/DoYiwm7c4qw/m/49SnkDiAK10J) ring a bell? The lead-up is different (a discussion of conservatives vs communists vs foreigners), the philosopher is different (Socrates), but the punchline is nearly the same and "damn foreigner" is used quite a bit. (If this is correct, I haven't managed to track down the original cartoon itself, but I thought this might helps others look) It's also possible that the Google Groups person is the one misremembering instead of you.

Comment: @bobble, That's probably it!